# When running Python + Kivy program including multiprocessing, white blank screen appears

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to use Kivy program including multiprocessing process.
Sample code worked as i thought;however, a blank white screen which does not accept the operation appeared. It appeared just when i started the multiprocessing process.

I already know that using threading.Thread, the blank screen won't appear;however, an actual program that i want to implement needs multiprocessing process.
How can i remove this blank screen?
This is what i saw.

[image]

P.S.

Considering comments, maybe it's a peculiar problem on windows.
I'm using windows 10, Python 3.6.4.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
import time
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, freeze_support

sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())

Builder.load_string('''
<TestScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical" # place object vertically
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'TITLE'
            font_size: 150
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Button:
            text: 'start'
            on_press: root.start_mp()
        Button:
            text: 'stop'
            on_press: root.stop_time()
''')


def count_time(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print('count={}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(1)

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
        return sm

class TestScreen(Screen):

    p1 = mp.Process(target=count_time, args=(10, ))
    def start_mp(self):
        self.p1 = mp.Process(target=count_time, args=(10, ))
        self.p1.start()

    def stop_time(self):
        self.p1.terminate()
        print(datetime.now())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Comment: I tried to run your code on my phone. It seems fine. I don't see any white blank screen when I tap the start button. Here is what I [saw](http://imgur.com/hysj6K6). And here is the [output](https://m.imgur.com/gUTJoEm) of the log.

Comment: I also don't see any white screen on Ubuntu. Note that you don't need to  define the `Process` twice.= (the class level `p1 = ` is unnecessary). The `terminate()` call also doesn't work on Linux, unless you add code to handle SIGTERM.

Comment: I ran your code on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.2, and I do see the white screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is the `ScreenManager` that you create at the start of your file. Move the `sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())` into the `build` method of your app and it should work without creating a second screen.

After some research, it appears that the problem results from the new `Process` importing the original python script. Since the `sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())` is unprotected in the original file, it gets executed upon that import. So the solution is simply to put that command anywhere that is protected. So another possibility that will work is to move that command into the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block just before the `Test().run()` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It worked without appearing any white  screen after i move the sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition()) to the line just before the Test().run() line.